# How to disconnect when there is no incoming data in MQTT.js

Tags: mqtt

I implemented a client with mqtt.js and subscribed some channel.
Here, if the subscription message does not come in for 30 seconds, I want to implement auto-disconnection, but I don't know how.
If KeepAlive is set to 0, PingRequest is not thrown but the connection is not terminated. What should I do?

```js
   let option = {
      port: config.mqtt_port,
      keepalive: 0,
    };
    mqtt.connect(config.mqtt_addr, option);
```

Comment: i'm using mosquitto broker

Comment: maybe you can set up an if statement and close it manually using:

`mqtt.end()`

Comment: `keepalive` set to zero does not do what you think it does. Read the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349238) section 3.1.2.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting with `keepalive: 0` tells the broker that he will never disconnect this client because of inactivity and there are no pings sent by the client at all.

Using `keepalive: 20` e.g. (broker waits 1.5 * keepalive before disconnecting client) seems not to be the way to go here either since it requires you to prevent your client from sending pings to get disconnected and is clearly a doubtful misusage of the `keepalive` mechanism

I recommend to handle this on the client side exclusively by using a timer which fires after 30 s where `mqtt.end()` is called to cleanly disconnect your client and within the onMessage-callback the timer should get resetted

Comment: i made timer like what you told. thank a lot :)